# Linq query to return all records with select new statement

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have table teacher and table student, for each record in table 'teacher' will have more than one record in table 'student'. Here is my model class

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<StudentsDTO> Students{ get; set; } 
}
```

here is my linq query am trying to get the records

```
     var st = (from tt in context.Teachers
                                    join ss in context.Students
                                    on tt.ID equals ss.teacherID
                                    where tt.TypeID == 2
                                    select new Test
                                    {
                                        Id = tt.ID,
                                        Text = tt.Text,
                                        Students= new List<StudentsDTO>()
                                        {
                                            new StudentsDTO()
                                            {
                                                Name= ss.Name,
                                                Id= ss.StudentID
                                            }
                                        }.ToList()
                                    }).ToList();
            return st;
```

am not able to get collection of students for each record in teachers table,how to do this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: am not getting collection of students records in the object, if there are two matching records in students table for one teacher record, its returning 2 records. Am expecting test.cs should have { id, text, Students count 2}

Comment: Looks like you'd need a "group by" to do what you're wanting.

Comment: @EricSmith, can you share some example on above scenario

Comment: In the above Linq query, don't you mean: ``... on tt.ID == ss.TeacherID ...``

Comment: yes it is, updated the question

Comment: @EricSmith `join` in query comprehension uses `equals` not `==`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used the proper entity framework class definitions for one-to-many relationships, your query would be much simpler. You wouldn't even have to use a join, because Entity Framework would do that for you.

see [Entity Framework Configure One-to-Many Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

If one Teacher has zero or more Students and every Student has exactly one Teacher, the one-to-many is modeled as follows:

```
class Teacher
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // a Teacher has zero or more Students:
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // a Student has exactly one Teacher, via foreign key TeacherId
    public int TeacherId {get; set;}
    public virtual Teacher Teacher {get; set;}
    ...
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

Because proper [Code First Conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) are used, this is all that is needed to model the one-to-many relationship between Teachers and Students.

> In entity framework, the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

If you want different Table names, or column names, you'll have to use Attributes or fluent API, but the Id remains the same: a Teacher has an ICollection to the many Students it has, and a Student has a foreign key and a property to the one Teacher it has.

Having defined your model correctly makes your query much simpler and more intuitive:

```
var result = myDbContext.Teachers                // from the set of Teachers
    .Where(teacher => teacher.TypeId == 2)       // take all teachers with TypeId 2
    .Select(teacher => new Test                  // from every remaining Teacher,
    {                                            // create one Test object
        Id = teacher.Id,                         // With Id is Teach Id
        Text = teacher.Text,                     // Text is teacher.Text
        Students = teacher.Students              
            .Select(student => new StudentDTO    // from every Student of this Teacher
            {                                    // create a StudentDTO object
                Id = student.ID,                 // with Id = student.Id
                Name= student.Name,              // Name is student.Name
            })
            .ToList(),                           // create a list of these StudentDTOs
     })
     .ToList();                                  // create a list of all Test objects
```

My experience is that since I model all my Entity Framework classes correctly, I rarely have to create Joins anymore. I usually think in collections instead of joined tables. Entity Framework will know which (group)join must be executed.

For instance: if you want the Names of all Students of the Teacher with a certain TeacherCode:

```
IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentsOfTeacher(string teacherCode)
{
    return myDbContext.Students
       .Where(student => student.Teacher.TeacherCode == teacherCode);
}
```

Entity Framework will do the join of the Students and the Teachers on TeacherId for you.

> If you want to do a group-join (an item with all its sub-items, a Teacher with all his Students), start on the one-side. If you want to do a flat join (a Student with this Teacher) start on the many-side.

Apart from simpler linq queries, proper modelling also hides the way the database is modeled. Users of your dbContext won't have to change their code if your internal model changes.

For instance, if you change the Teacher-Student relation into a many-to-many relation, meaning that a Teacher may have many Students and a Student may have many Teachers, the definition of your Teachers class is not changed, thus above queries won't have to change as long as the classes won't change.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a left join, replace the `in ssj` with `in ssj.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

```
var st = (from tt in context.Teachers
          where tt.TypeID == 2
          join ss in context.Students
          on tt.ID equals ss.teacherID into ssj
          select new Test {
              Id = tt.ID,
              Text = tt.Text,
              Students = (from ss in ssj
                          select new StudentsDTO() {
                              Name = ss.Name,
                              Id = ss.StudentID
                           }).ToList()
          }).ToList();

return st;
```

This uses what is called a group join in LINQ - the query matches each tt with a collection of ss in ssj (i.e. { tt, group of ss }).

Comment: What should be the return type in this example?

Comment: @Veswanth `List<Test>`.